# Is there a way to copy all the Git Repo information from one machine to another in Source Tree

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am in the process of setting up a new devmachine (joys of self isolation) and am trying to work out if there is a simple way of geting all the repo information from one machine to another in bitbucket. I am not trying to copy the repos, I am happy re pulling them. What I want to copy are the Source Tree details like the Link, where the repo is stored locally etc so that when I open bit bucket all my repos are there and I can start pullling branches as I need to.

I have 30+ projects that are in Gitlab I need to copy and I dont fancy manually resetting source tree up again on my machine.

Is there an easy way to do this?

To clarify I have a new laptop I am setting up so I can work remotely. I have installed the bit bucket app which I use to manage my git process, we use gitlab to stir our repos. I am looking for a way to transfer the information bit bucket stores about each of the git repos rather then having to go through the whole clone process all over again for each repo

Comment: Hi. I do not understand what you mean by "resetting bit bucket up on my machine" . Could you please provide more details about the operations you would like to automate ?

Comment: Updated the question is hopefully clearer.

Comment: What you call "the bit bucket app" : is it "SourceTree" ?

Comment: Sorry yes source tree question updated again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer the "git setup" from a workstation to another, you could simply copy the directories from one disk to another.

The necessary elements would be :

- your global `.gitconfig` file
- all the local clones of your repos

---

Your global `.gitconfig` file :

It should be located in your home directory, copy it to your new home directory.

If you want to know for sure where to find this file, open a terminal, and type :

```
git config --global --show-origin --list
```